# search and replace regular expression

Tags: regex, regedit

I have some German sentences which I need to replace by some other words. E.g. I have a column:

```
vorrätig - in 5-6 Werktagen bei Ihnen
vorrätig - in 2-3 Werktagen bei Ihnen
lieferbar Ende Januar
lieferbar Ende May
```

Where ever the word `vorrÃƒÂ¤tig` appears I want that column value to be `Auf Lager`. Similarly where ever `lieferbar` appears, I want the value to be `Nicht auf Lager`.

I.e. the final value of the column should be:

```
Auf Lager
Auf Lager
Nicht auf Lager
Nicht auf Lager
```

Can you please let me know what should be the 'search regex' and 'replace regex'?

Comment: what language/interface are you using to do the regex?

Comment: your search regex is `vorrätig` and replace is `Auf Lager`. What's the question?

Comment: Also, http://www.regexpal.com/ is your friend.

Comment: Java. Please notice, I need to replace the whole sentence.

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm, doesn't sound like you need a regex for this though.

Comment: Yes, I think you are much better off just using a string replace function than using regex.

Comment: no, I need to supply these input to the java class which is trying to read a csv file. I want it to replace the whole column where ever it encounters the word vorrätig, by Auf Lager. Similarly for other. I need to provide what's the search expression and what's the replace expression. I get, i need to search for 'vorrätig' and I need to replace by 'Auf Lager'. But that will result 'Auf Lager - in 5-6 Werktagen bei Ihnen'. I just want the output to be 'Auf Lager'

Comment: This is what works for me in notepad: Search string: ^vorrÃƒÂ¤tig (.)*$  Repalce string: Auf Lager